# Como fazer uma consulta que traz apenas a contagem de uma sequência ininterrupta?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Quero a contagem de valores ininterruptas do ano atual para trás, até ocorrer o primeiro `NULL`.

Exemplo:

> Várias pessoas fazem doações para uma ONG anualmente e isso está
>   armazenado em uma base de dados, gostaria de saber quantos anos uma
>   pessoa fez doações de forma ininterrupta, ou seja, quantos anos consecutivos foram feitas doações a parti do ano atual.

Tabela Doações:

```
Pessoa_id | Valor | Ano  
9999      | 100   | 2009  
9999      | 100   | 2010  
9999      | 100   | 2011  
9999      | NULL  | 2012  
9999      | 100   | 2013  
9999      | NULL  | 2014  
9999      | 100   | 2015  
9999      | 100   | 2016  
9999      | 100   | 2017
```

O resultado deve ser 3, pois contando o ano atual`(2017)` mais os dois anos que ele doou `(2016 e 2015)`.

Comment: Estou usando a versão 11

Comment: Me refiro a versão do SQL Server: 2017, 2016, 2014, 2012 etc. Se não souber, não há problema.

Comment: Imaginava, estou usando o SS 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **GAPS and ISLANDS**

Eis solução que utiliza o princípio de pesquisa por *gaps and islands*.

```
-- código #1 v4
with 
C as (
SELECT Pessoa_Id, Ano, Valor,
       ilha= (Ano - DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by Pessoa_Id order by Ano)) 
  from Doação
  where Valor is not null
)
SELECT Pessoa_Id, 
       count(*) as Ininterrupto,
       min(Valor) as [Menor valor],
       max(Valor) as [Maior valor],
       avg(Valor) as Média,
       sum(Valor) as Total  
  from C
  group by Pessoa_Id, ilha
  having max(Ano) = 2017;
```

Código adaptado do artigo [Solving Gaps and Islands with Enhanced Window Functions](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions). Caso a versão do SQL Server seja 2012, ou mais recente, você pode utilizar as novas funções window, conforme consta no artigo.

---

> **CTE RECURSIVA**

Eis outra solução, baseada em CTE recursiva que inicia a leitura por todas as linhas do ano de 2017 que tenham valor informado e continua lendo em ordem inversa sequencial, até encontrar ausência de valor (NULL) ou quebra na coluna de ano.

```
-- código #2
with bloco2017 as (
SELECT Pessoa_id, Ano, Valor
  from Doação
  where Ano = 2017 
        and Valor is not null

union all 
SELECT T1.Pessoa_id, T1.Ano, T1.Valor
  from Doação as T1
       inner join bloco2017 as T2 on T1.Pessoa_Id = T2.Pessoa_Id
                                     and T1.Ano = (T2.Ano -1)
  where T1.Valor is not null
)
SELECT Pessoa_Id, 
       count(*) as Ininterrupto,
       min(Valor) as [Menor valor],
       max(Valor) as [Maior valor],
       avg(Valor) as Média,
       sum(Valor) as Total
  from bloco2017
  group by Pessoa_Id;
```

---

Para testar:

```
-- código #3 v2
CREATE TABLE Doação (
   Pessoa_id int,
   Valor money,
   Ano smallint
);

INSERT into Doação values 
 (1212, 80, 2009),
 (1212, 90, 2010),
 (1212, 100, 2011),
 (1212, NULL, 2012),
 (1212, 120, 2013),
 (1212, NULL, 2014),
 (1212, NULL, 2015),
 (1212, 150, 2016),
 (1212, 160, 2017);

INSERT into Doação values 
 (1213, 300, 2009),
 (1213, 200, 2010),
 (1213, 100, 2011),
 (1213, 50, 2012),
 (1213, NULL, 2013),
 (1213, 20, 2014),
 (1213, 800, 2016),
 (1213, 100, 2017);
```

Para a pessoa 1213 propositalmente não consta informação sobre o ano de 2015, para demonstrar que o código também trata quebra na sequência (isto é, ausência de linha).

Comment: Não tinha conhecimento sobre Gaps e Islands. Foi muito útil o exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a query seria mais ou menos assim, trabalhando com variáveis:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT 
    MAX(total)
FROM(
SELECT
    @total:=@total+1 AS total,
    IFNULL(valor, @total:=0) as aux,
    valor,
    ano
FROM doacao
HAVING aux != 0) AS aux;
```